# Getting data from socket io kotlin

Tags: android, socket.io, kotlin

I want to make an application for android in kotlin and I'm using socket io for getting data from server. The problem is, I couldn't find anywhere how to write "socket.on" method and to do something with the data, only ".emit" method only in Java. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:

a singleton:

```
class WebSocket{

private var mSocket: Socket? = null

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: WebSocket? = null
    fun getInstance() =
        INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
            INSTANCE ?: WebSocket().also {
                INSTANCE = it
            }
        }
}

fun createSocket(id:String) {

    val mUrl = "https://myserverurl"

    try {
        val opts = IO.Options()
        opts.forceNew = true
        opts.reconnection = true
        opts.secure = true
        opts.query = "id=${id}"
        mSocket = IO.socket(mUrl,opts)
        mSocket!!.connect()
    } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}

fun onNewMessage(cb:(fromId:String,
                     toId:String,
                     fromDeviceId:String,
                     senderName:String,
                     receiverName:String,
                     message:String,
                     productId:String,
                     timestamp:String ) -> Unit): Emitter.Listener {

    return Emitter.Listener { args ->

        val data = args[0] as JSONObject

        val senderName = data.getString("sender_name")
        val receiverName = data.getString("receiver_name")
        val message = data.getString("message")
        val fromId = data.getString("from_id")
        val toId = data.getString("to_id")
        val fromDeviceId = data.getString("from_device_id")
        val productId = data.getString("product_id")
        val timestamp = data.getString("timestamp")

        cb( fromId,
            toId,
            fromDeviceId,
            senderName,
            receiverName,
            message,
            productId,
            timestamp )

    }
}

fun getSocket():Socket? {
    return mSocket
}

}
```

In my service:

```
WebSocket.getInstance().createSocket(userId!!)
    val io = WebSocket.getInstance().getSocket()
    //val notifications = NotificationsHandler()

    io!!.on("message",
        WebSocket.getInstance().onNewMessage { fromId, toId, fromDeviceId, senderName, receiverName, message, productId, timestamp ->
            
            //here you handle fromId, toId, fromDeviceId, senderName, receiverName, message, productId, timestamp

        })
```

This way, you can call `WebSocket.getInstance().getSocket()` (after creating a `Socket`), and the socket is ready to use in any activity.